# How can I override individual box colors with Plotly treemap

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I'm creating a treemap with Plotly that shows files in a repo by their size, with nesting for the directories. I'd like to assign colors based on my own arbitrary rules. For example "files that start with `test_` are red" or "binary files are blue". I'm not using a dataframe so I call `treemap()` like this:

```
fig = px.treemap(names=names, ids=ids, parents=parents, values=values, ...)
```

I was hoping to pass in a matching array that explicitly had the color of every node. The `treemap()` params `color` and `discrete_color_map` don't seem to work that way? Is there a way to specify the color of every box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `ids` and `color` and then have `color_discrete_map` override the color of every box. This example is a little weird based on my use case, but it works:

```
import plotly.express as px

def create_treemap():
    names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ids = ['a', 'a/b', 'a/c', 'a/c/d']
    parents = ['', 'a', 'a', 'a/c']
    values = [10, 5, 5, 2]

    colors = {
        'a': 'red',
        'a/b': 'green',
        'a/c': 'gold',
        'a/c/d': 'grey'
    }

    fig = px.treemap(names=names, ids=ids, parents=parents, values=values,
                    color=ids,
                    color_discrete_map=colors, 
                    branchvalues='total', title="my treemap")
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
    return fig

create_treemap().show()
```

which produces:

[image: resulting treemap]